# Managing URLs in a Django site inside a folder

Tags: python, django

So I have my Django project in a folder on my server, like so:

www.mydomain.com/myfolder/

The index page loads, but things like the css document don't because the paths are improper. Am I missing a shortcut? I looked through the settings.py documentation for a place to specify my site folder, but didn't find anything to help.

So example, if I specify this in my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Then it will look for my css doc on my */myfolder/login* page at:

```
http://mydomain.com/myfolder/login/static/stylesheet.css
```

If I specify:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then it will look for my css doc on my */myfolder/login* page at:

```
http://mydomain.com/static/stylesheet.css
```

Meanwhile, my css document is at:

```
http://mydomain.com/myfolder/static/stylesheet.css
```

Do I need to change everything and specify /myfolder/ before everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add path of you STATIC_ROOT in settings, and update urls.py file.

My example:

```
#settings.py 

....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static",)
#path to your static folder

#urls.py

...
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

....

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Django says this urls.py configuration use is not suitable for production use. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 1):

This question has a good practice solution on django tutorial:

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial06/#customize-your-app-s-look-and-feel

That you should create a `/static/appname/` folder inside each of your app, and then put the static files inside it.

So in your app, the static file url should turned into something like:

`http://mydomain.com/static/app_name/stylesheet.css`

Which won't collides with other app.

You'd better read the link I offered above, the tutorial shows a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just need to do this?

```
STATIC_URL = '/myfolder/static/'
```

Comment: STATIC_URL is where the static content is, not the site root.